# Quick overview of disk space on windows 7/ vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, disk-space

One feature I miss from xp is the ability to hover over disks and quickly see their used/total space.

Can anyone let me know if this can be turned on in vista/7 or any other solutions?

Comment: Have Windows 7 Ultimate here, it shows that info in all view styles for me, it just behaves a bit strange. It doesn't show info for disk C until I hover mouse over D so it shows info for that disk. After that it shows the info also for disk C.

Comment: I'm trying to find the info inside the start menu, like I could on xp. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Explorer displays that already directly:

[image: Explorer window, opened with “Computer”]

Comment: It depends what view the user has enabled for "My Computer"

Comment: Ok, but Details, Tiles and Content *do* display that information. Does anyone have so many things in “Computer” that “Small icons” are a viable view?

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to having my computer as a menu in the start menu, and just hovering without having to do more than one click.

I am basically looking for a way to find out this info with only one click from a clean desktop(apart from clicking on my computer, I don't want to load an entire win explorer window).